# Need help to increase code coverage for trigger?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am new for writing test class even I like to writing test class I tried to write test classes I am getting error Variables cannot be marked as tests. Please can any one help me out

trigger class:

```
trigger Rfleet_UpdateforecastAllCountry on Country_DCVF_Volume__c (after insert,after update,after delete) {
string TempYear;
Integer TempMonth;

Integer FinalVolume=0;
Integer FinalForecast=0;
set<id>Ikamids=new set<id>();
set<id>Accountids=new set<id>();

if(trigger.isinsert||trigger.isupdate ){
for(Country_DCVF_Volume__c Dcvfcount:trigger.new){
    if(Dcvfcount.IKAM_Data__c!=null){
        Ikamids.add(Dcvfcount.IKAM_Data__c);
        Accountids.add(Dcvfcount.Parent_Account__c);
    }
}
}
if(trigger.isdelete){
for(Country_DCVF_Volume__c Dcvfcount:trigger.old){
    if(Dcvfcount.IKAM_Data__c!=null){
        Ikamids.add(Dcvfcount.IKAM_Data__c);
        Accountids.add(Dcvfcount.Parent_Account__c);
    }
}
}
list<country_dcvf_volume__c>listVol=[select id,insertion_date__c, country__c, Year__c from country_dcvf_volume__c where IKAM_Data__c in:Ikamids and Parent_Account__c in:Accountids ORDER BY insertion_date__c desc limit 1];

 for(country_dcvf_volume__c FirstList :listVol){

 TempYear=string.Valueof(FirstList.Year__c);
 TempMonth=integer.valueof(FirstList.insertion_date__c.month());

 }
 list<IKAM_Data__c>finalcount=new list<IKAM_Data__c>();
 list<country_dcvf_volume__c> SecondSortedList=[select id,Country_forecast__c ,IKAM_Data__c, Delivered_volume__c from country_dcvf_volume__c where IKAM_Data__c in:Ikamids and Parent_Account__c in:Accountids and Year__c =:TempYear and CALENDAR_month(insertion_date__c)=:TempMonth ];
 list<IKAM_Data__c>Ikamupdate=[select id,Countries_delivered_volume__c,Countries_forecast__c from IKAM_Data__c where id in:Ikamids ];
 for(country_dcvf_volume__c FinalList :SecondSortedList){
   for(IKAM_Data__c updateIkam:Ikamupdate){

          FinalVolume +=integer.valueof(FinalList.Delivered_volume__c);
          FinalForecast +=integer.valueof(FinalList.Country_forecast__c);
          updateIkam.Countries_delivered_volume__c=FinalVolume; 
          updateIkam.Countries_forecast__c=FinalForecast ;
     }
 }

 update Ikamupdate;

}
```

My test class:

```
@isTest
private class Rfleet_UpdateforecastAllCountry_Test {
public static testmethod void Rfleet_UpdateforecastAllCountry_TestMethod{

Country_DCVF_Volume__c ContryDCVF = new Country_DCVF_Volume__c(
Country__c='Algeria',
Parent_Account__c='Bosch',
Region__c='France',
Insertion_date__c='11/11/2015',
KAM__c='Ganz Bruno',
Delivered_volume__c='1',
IKAM_Data__c='IKAM-D-4'
);
insert ContryDCVF;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few of your code is running on the delete trigger ... you are not deleting any records in your test.

The second part most of your code depends on a query on country_dcvf_volume__c, IKAM_Data__c and dependency on account which means you need to insert them as part of your test data to meet the condition in your trigger.

The tests are generally is not only for code coverage. you should test that the functionality is working as expected. You should use system.assert to make sure the output of the test is as required.

Comment: @ Amr Ibrahim I agree your point. I am new for test class I go forward to step by step could you please help me out.

Comment: Have a look on below links from SF
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm